# Intel S3500 need over provisioning in ESXi?

Tags: vmware-esxi, ssd

I have 8x Intel DC S3500 SSD's in Raid 10. I am setting up the datastore in ESXi, however I am not sure how much to over provision or if its needed. I know the s3500 are enterprise oriented but not the same as s3700 for example.

Does the S3500 have garbage collection so that over provisioning isn't needed like consumer ssd's need?

Thank you

Comment: Eh? Virtually all SSDs, excepting possibly the very earliest ones on the market a decade ago, do garbage collection. It's much more important to check if the RAID controller supports TRIM/unmap.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't worry about it.

Treat these like consumable parts. You're using RAID, so design around the potential for failure.

Do you have any information about the RAID controller in use, since that may be a factor if performance is the primary concern.

Comment: Yes forgot ro mention that. Its a Dell R720 with h710p mini; raid settings 64k, write thru, no read ahead. The card has 1gb cache and bbu but I had read that using write back will produce more writes to the ssd which would impact the life overall.